# como exporto un datagrid a excel

Tags: asp.net

quiero exportar un datagrid, su botón funciona pero cuando lo abro en excel, este me dice que la extensión tiene otro formato.

otra cosa, si le doy aceptar al el excel, la hoja no muestra nada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo

```
    public class CustomersBe
    {
        public string Almacen { get; set; }
        public string reftallacolor { get; set; }
        public string referencia { get; set; }
        public string talla { get; set; }
        public string color { get; set; }
        public int  idcurva { get; set; }
        public string CantUnidades { get; set; }
        public string CantModificadas { get; set; }
        public string Zona { get; set; }
        public string coleccion { get; set; }
        public string clasifica { get; set; }
        public string silueta { get; set; }
        public int Cantinv { get; set; }
        public double UnidadesFactu { get; set; }
        public string rotacionSemana { get; set; }
        public string rotacionMes { get; set; }
        public string rotacion2Meses { get; set; }
        public string Sugerido { get; set; }
    }

    public static List<CustomersBe> lista = new List<CustomersBe>();
    //private object runat;

    public object server { get; private set; }

    public void CargarData()

    {

       SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection();
        conexion.ConnectionString = "Data Source=192.168.1.200;Initial Catalog=LAURASA;User Id=sa;Password=laurasa";
        conexion.Open();
        try
        {
            string consulta = @"select almacen,RefTallaColor,Referencia,Talla,color,IDCurva,CantUnidades,CantModificadas from Analisis_Curva  WHERE Referencia = '" + ddlReferencia.SelectedValue + "' and almacen  = '" + ddlAlmacen.SelectedValue + "'";
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, conexion);
                SqlDataReader lector = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (lector.Read())
                {
                    var customers = new CustomersBe();
                    customers.Almacen = (string)lector[0];
                    customers.reftallacolor = (string)lector[1];
                    customers.referencia = (string)lector[2];
                    customers.talla = (string)lector[3];
                    customers.color = (string)lector[4];
                    customers.idcurva = (int)lector[5];
                    customers.CantUnidades = (string)lector[6];
                    customers.CantModificadas = (string)lector[7];

                    lista.Add(customers);
                }
                grvAnalisis.DataSource = lista;
                grvAnalisis.DataBind();
                conexion.Close();

        }
       catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

    }
    protected void grvAnalisis_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        grvAnalisis.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        CargarData();

    }
    protected void btnGridviewToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

        grvAnalisis.EnableViewState = false;

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=AnalisisDeCurva.xls");
       // Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        Page page = new Page();
        Form HtmlForm = new Form();
        Page.Controls.Add(Form);
        Form.Controls.Add(grvAnalisis);

        //Page.RenderControl(hw);

        grvAnalisis.AllowPaging = true;
            this.CargarData();

       //grvAnalisis.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;

        foreach(TableCell cell in grvAnalisis.HeaderRow.Cells)
        {
              cell.BackColor=grvAnalisis.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
         }
            foreach (GridViewRow row in grvAnalisis.Rows)
            {
                row.BackColor = Color.White;
                foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)btn
                {
                    if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = grvAnalisis.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //cell.BackColor = grvAnalisis.RowStyle.BackColor;
                        cell.BackColor = Color.White;
                    }
                    cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                }
            }  
       // grvAnalisis.RenderControl(hw);

       // string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
        Response.Charset = "iso-8859-1";
        Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
        //Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default;
        Response.Write(sw);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        //Response.Flush();
        Response.End(); 
    }
}
```

el problema esta en el  btnGridviewToExcel

Comment: El problema es simplemente la extensión. Probablemente estas guardando en formato moderno, cuya extension debería ser `xlsx` y sin embargo tu en tu código intentas guardarlo como `xls` (`AnalisisDeCurva.xls`) Cambia `AnalisisDeCurva.xls` por `AnalisisDeCurva.xlsx` y ese error no te saldrá

Comment: pero no me muestra nada en el excel

Comment: Lo que estas escribiendo es el contenido de `sw` (un StreamWriter), pero en ningun momento metes ningun dato en el

Comment: entonces que le meto al sw

Answer (score 0):

Como me ha funcionado es con la extensión de `xlsx` y con este `contentType` `application/application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`, esto pasa con las nuevas versiones de office ya cuesta mas hacerlas compatibles con el `contentType`

```
protected void btnGridviewToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

    grvAnalisis.EnableViewState = false;

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=AnalisisDeCurva.xlsx");
   // Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    Page page = new Page();
    Form HtmlForm = new Form();
    Page.Controls.Add(Form);
    Form.Controls.Add(grvAnalisis);

    //Page.RenderControl(hw);

    grvAnalisis.AllowPaging = true;
        this.CargarData();

   //grvAnalisis.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;

    foreach(TableCell cell in grvAnalisis.HeaderRow.Cells)
    {
          cell.BackColor=grvAnalisis.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
     }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grvAnalisis.Rows)
        {
            row.BackColor = Color.White;
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)btn
            {
                if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = grvAnalisis.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                }
                else
                {
                    //cell.BackColor = grvAnalisis.RowStyle.BackColor;
                    cell.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
                cell.CssClass = "textmode";
            }
        }  
   // grvAnalisis.RenderControl(hw);

   // string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
    Response.Charset = "iso-8859-1";
    Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
    //Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Default;
    Response.Write(sw);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    //Response.Flush();
    Response.End(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción que es bastante util es usar la librería [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) descargas el dll lo importas a la referencias de tu proyecto y puedes crear el siguiente procedimiento para mandarle tu dataset con el llenas el datagrid para que te genere un libro de Excel perfectamente funcional.

Primero importas los espaciados de nombres a usar:

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
```

Creamos la función que hara usa de la librería de ClosedXML:

```
 public void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt)
    {
        XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();

        using (wb) {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=data.xlsx");

            MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            using (MyMemoryStream) {
                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

Luego la invocarías desde tu código de la siguiente manera **(Ojo: debes llenar tu dataset antes)** :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        //Dataset debe ser llenado antes
        ExportToExcel(ds.Tables[0]);
    }
```